# calculating the solar declination

Tags: sun

I was looking at this page

http://www.illustratingshadows.com/www-formulae-collection.pdf

and found the equation used for estimating the solar declination (sun declination). One problem, though, I wish to cite this equation in my work and was hoping there would be a textbook that shows this same equation? Can anyone suggest a reference for this other than a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [Google-book](http://books.google.com/) search of "solar declination" lead me to [this Google-book preview](http://books.google.com/books?id=B_E33NK7-YkC&pg=PA55&dq=solar+declination&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WhpUUqG2FYyC9gTfnoCYCw&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=solar%20declination&f=false) of *Solar Energy Engineering: Processes and Systems*
 by Soteris A. Kalogirou. This book gives the Spencer formula as Equation (2.6), on page 55.